# Can't display radio button value using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble displaying the value of a radio button that I click in my basic web app that I am currently working on.

Here is my ajax.js file:

```
$('#selection').change(function() {
    var selected_value = $("input[name='kobegreat']:checked").val();

   $.ajax( {
       url: "kobegreat.php",
       data: selected_value,
       type: "POST",
       datatype: "json",

       success: function(json) {
           var test1 = $("<p></p>").text(json["name"]);
           $("h3").append(test1);
           alert("AJAX was a success");
      },
      cache: false
  });
});
```

And my kobegreat.php file:

```
<?php

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD] == "POST") {
       $value = $POST['kobegreat'];
       $return = $_POST;
       if($return["name"] == "") {
           $return["name"] = $value;
       }
       echo json_encode($return);
   }
?>
```

HTML code I am trying to display my value on:

```
<h2>Select a Great Kobe Moment.</h2>
<form id="selection" method="get">
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe1" checked/>Kobe1
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe2"/>Kobe2
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe3"/>Kobe3
</form>

<div id="target">
    <h3>Great Kobe Moment!</h3>
</div>
```

All I want is for the program to display the value underneath one of my headings I have on my webpage, but it won't do so. I get the alert that AJAX ran in the completed: section, but I am also getting an error in the log that says json is not defined.
Look everywhere for help on this problem, thanks ahead of time for the help.

Comment: `.text(json["name])` you are missing something  here

Comment: Also `date: selected_value,`... It should be `data: {date: selected_value},` right ?

Comment: you are getting wrong values in php here $POST['kobegreat']

Comment: also `datatype: "json",` dataType:'json';

Comment: fixed all of those errors, they weren't like that in my files. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: also `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD]` is missing a high comma, should be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. I recommend you to use a good IDE like Netbeans.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly then you just try to pass the name of the selected radio button to your kobegreat.php file and return it back as response. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Select a Great Kobe Moment.</h2>
<form id="selection" method="get">
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe1" checked/>Kobe1
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe2"/>Kobe2
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe3"/>Kobe3
</form>

<div id="target">
    <h3>Great Kobe Moment!</h3>
</div>

<script>
    $('#selection').change
    (
        function() 
        {
            var selected_value = $("input[name='kobegreat']:checked").val();

            $.ajax
            ( 
                {
                    url: "kobegreat.php",
                    dataType : "json",
                    method: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { selected_value : selected_value },

                    success: function(response)
                    {
                       var test1 = "<p>"+response+"</p>";
                       $("h3").append(test1);
                       alert("AJAX was a success");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**kobegreat.php**

```
<?php

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
   {
       $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "selected_value");

       if (isset($value))
       {
           echo json_encode($value);
       }
   }
```

**Advice**: You should never access the superglobal $_POST array directly, always use a filter function, because it is more secure.

Comment: is it necessary to use `$.ajax` and do you need `json`?

Comment: I'm going to need it for what I plan on doing next which is pulling image links from a mysql database and displaying an image according to what radio button has been selected.

Comment: I fixed my initial problems but I'm still having a problem doing what I truly want. If you could take a look at my updated code and possibly give me some insight onto how I could fix my problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is very unfair @Scott, you should  create another question instead of completly changing your initial question. I solved your initial problem and you should accept this if it helped you.

Comment: I would have started another question, but I'm only limited to one question per 3 days.